# How do I wrap MembershipUser

Tags: asp.net

How would i wrap MembershipUser so that the call below returns. Reason for wrapping is I would like the return result to be an interface to I can mock the user.

```
public IMembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)        
        {
            var user = Membership.GetUser(username, userIsOnline));

            //Do something 
            return WrappedUser;
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I'm afraid you can't do this becuase..**

System.Web.Security.MembershipUser type does not **inherit** from any special base-type and also it's not declared as **partial**, so there's no way you can do this.

But if you let us know what exactly you want to do, we can come up with alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by implementing your own `SiteMembershipProvider`. Here's an example snippet of an implementation I did a while back:

```
public class CustomMembershipUser : MembershipUser
{
    public UserItem UserItem { get; private set; }

    public CustomMembershipUser(string providerName, UserItem user)
        : base(providerName, user.UserName, "user_" + user.UserID, user.Email,
            null, null, true, !user.IsCurrent, DateTime.MinValue, 
            DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        this.UserItem = user;
    }
}

public class SiteMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    ....

    private static MembershipUser GetMembershipUser(UserItem user)
    {
        return new CustomMembershipUser(_membershipProviderName,user);
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        // Load user
        return GetMembershipUser(foundUser);
    }

    ....
}
```

In Web.Config:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="SiteMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="SiteMembershipProvider" type="SiteMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" connectionStringName="myConnectionString"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

This should default your entire site to use the new `MembershipProvider` called `SiteMembershipProvider`.

Have [a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) or [here for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx) to implement the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class which implements your IMemberShipUser interface and internally stores a reference to the "real" MembershipUser.

The properties and methods on your wrapped class could then simply delegate to the real reference.

Edit - A super simple example below:

```
using System.Web.Security;
namespace Example
{
    public interface IMembershipUser
    {
        string UserName { get; }    
        string Email { get; }    
    }

    public class WrappedMembershipUser: IMembershipUser
    {
        private readonly MembershipUser realUser;

        public WrappedMembershipUser(MembershipUser realUser)
        {
            this.realUser = realUser;
        }
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return realUser.UserName; }
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get { return realUser.Email; }
        }
    }
}
```